# How to type the small letter corresponding to $\mathscr{G}$?

Tags: fonts, symbols, amsfonts

how to type [image]???

This is a math symbol in the renormalization group theory. The `mathrsfs` can only support capital letter.

Sorry everybody, I made a serious mistake! I thought the G in the picture is a lowercase letter. But in fact it is already a uppercase letter.

I'am very sorry.

Comment: On the basis of the comments to the answers, I'm closing here. As the questioner actually did want a capital letter, it's not really clear what an answer would be :-)

Answer (score 5):

Does this help?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calligra,amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\g}{\text{\calligra g}\,}

\begin{document}

$\g\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathcal{W}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could mark the code, use {} selected from the top of the input window to mark the code as shown above.

Comment: This is not the same font as I posted.

Comment: I made a serious mistake! I thought the G in the picture is a lowercase letter. But in fact it is already a uppercase letter.

I'am very sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[version=setB,StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
$\delta \mathscr{G_i}$
\end{document}
```

Now, first You have to define a math font, e.g. `XITS Math` and then the letter G will appear as required. **You need to compile this with xelatex to get the output**.

[image]

An alternative using the `mathrsfs` package. The MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
$\delta~\mathscr{G}_i$
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use **pdflatex** itself to compile this. And to remove the gap, just remove the `~` symbol.

Comment: I think the OP was asking for a *lowercase* script `g`.

Comment: What if I still need the uppercase letter '\mathscr{G}'?

Comment: I need both the uppercase and lowercase letter in this font. How to do that?

Comment: The first example can also be compiled with `lualatex`.

Comment: @ChenTongyu the example shows uppercase only, if you want lower case replace the G by g

Comment: @subhamsoni I need to write both uppercase and lowercase letters in the same  document, that is, \mathscr{G} and \mathscr{g} should give the uppercase and the lowercase respectively. Your method destroy the original command(\mathscr{}).

Comment: sorry I made a serious mistake! I thought the G in the picture is a lowercase letter. But in fact it is already a uppercase letter.

I'am very sorry.

Comment: If the answer satisfies your question, you can very well accept it @ChenTongyu

Answer (score 2):

If a given font family provides only uppercase letters and no lowercase letters, it's generally going to be tricky to find a substitute font whose lowercase letters provide a stylistic match to the uppercase letters of the initial font.

You may want to give the `Zapf Chancery` script font a try. You'll notice immediately that its letters are both less slanted and less ornate than the uppercase letters of the  `mathrsfs` script font. Of course, this may be to your liking. (Speaking strictly for myself, I find that the script-G provided by `mathrsfs` looks out of place next to the `\delta` character from the Computer Modern family.)

For sure, if you decide to use `\mathpzc{g}` in your document, you should also use the same font family for the uppercase-G, i.e., write `\mathpzc{G}`. Don't use `\mathscr{G}` next to `\mathpzc{g}` unless you want to set up a massive visual clash..
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it} % load "Zapf Chancery" as a math alphabet
\begin{document}
$\mathpzc{g}$ $\mathpzc{G}$ \quad $\delta\mathpzc{g}_i$ $\delta\mathpzc{G}_i$ 

\medskip
for comparison: $\delta\mathscr{G}_i$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I made a serious mistake! I thought the G in the picture is a lowercase letter. But in fact it is already a uppercase letter.

I'am very sorry.

Comment: @ChenTongyu - Thanks for this clarification. Would you suggest closing (not deleting!) your posting as your query seems to have rested on a misunderstanding?