# Lowercase scripted G

Tags: fonts, symbols, characters

On [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/181172/127245) answer, `pablos` almost solved my problem. I am desperate in finding a better-looking lowercase `g`. Indeed, if I just use :

```
\usepackage{calligra}
\newcommand{\g}{\textup{\large\calligra g}\,}
```

then the output is the following :

[image]

I am having several concerns about this approach :

1. The scripted `g` is pixellated (I don't really mind, as it is only meant to be use in regularly-sized equations).
2. The scripted `g` is too italicized, it becomes weird in equations, and especially in inline math :

[image]

3. (However, this is probably related to 2.) The tail of the scripted `g` descends too low, and the top part part is too low too.

Here are all my concerns in a drawing, and for reference, the vanilla `\ell` command, fitting what I'm expecting :

[image]

Does anyone have any clues on how to fix this ? I tried using `\rotatebox`es, but the fact that this letter is highly pixellated rendered terrible and blurry. Also, I tried several other fonts, none of which providing a scripted `g` like the `calligra` one...

*P.S. :* I feel very sorry if that kind of question is unwelcomed here, but I have been trying for more than an hour now... I hope I'm not asking a "[do it for me](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8566/127245)" question out of despair for finding a solution...

Comment: There are a few 8-bit fonts that have a `\mathcal{g}`, including `stix2`. All fonts usable with `unicode-math` do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you install the `calligra-type1` package, you can `\usepackage{calligra}` and get non-pixelated fonts.  Then, I suggest the use of `\unslant` (limited to the pdflatex engine), detailed here: [Upright Greek font fitting to Computer Modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calligra,amsmath,amssymb,lmodern}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.25]{\slantbox[#1]{$#2$}}

\newcommand{\g}{\unslant[-.5]{$\calligra g$}\,}

\begin{document}

\textit{g} $\g\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathcal{W}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're a LaTeX guru ! Thanks !

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq You are welcome. Keep in mind however, the `\unslant` only works for the `pdflatex` engine.

Comment: That's the one I'm using ! I forgot to mention I tried fontspec but it needed xetex, which I didn't manage to have working !

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq A good font resource for `pdflatex`: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/